# Extract text from 2 strings from selected Outlook email

Tags: regex, excel, vba, outlook

I have code to import email body data from Outlook to Excel. I only need Name, ID, code from the email.

I have done everything except to extract the ID from a fixed sentence:

> cn=SVCLMCH,OU=Users,OU=CX,DC=dm001,DC=corp,DC=dcsa,DC=com

The id is SVCLMCH in this case, that means I need to extract the text between **"cn="** and **",OU=Users"**.

```
Sub import_code()

Dim O As Outlook.Application
Set O = New Outlook.Application

Dim ONS As Outlook.Namespace
Set ONS = O.GetNamespace("MAPI")

Dim OMAIL As Outlook.MailItem
Set OMAIL = Nothing

Dim ws As Object
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Import code from Outlook")

Dim rcount As Long
Dim vText As Variant
Dim sText As String
Dim i As Long

If O.ActiveExplorer.Selection.Count = 0 Then
    msgbox "No Items selected!", vbCritical, "Error"
End If

On Error Resume Next

'Process each selected record
rcount = ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count
For Each OMAIL In O.ActiveExplorer.Selection
    sText = OMAIL.Body
    vText = Split(sText, Chr(13))
    'Find the next empty line of the worksheet
     rcount = rcount + 1
    'Check each line of text in the message body
    For i = UBound(vText) To 0 Step -1

        If InStr(1, vText(i), "Password Generated and set for:") > 0 Then
            vItem = Split(vText(i), Chr(58))
            ws.Range("A" & rcount) = Trim(vItem(1))
        End If

        If InStr(1, vText(i), "cn=") > 0 Then
            vItem = Split(vText(i), Chr(58))
            ws.Range("b" & rcount) = Trim(vItem(1))
    End If

    If InStr(1, vText(i), "Password:") > 0 Then
        vItem = Split(vText(i), Chr(58))
        ws.Range("c" & rcount) = Trim(vItem(1))
    End If

Next i

Next OMAIL

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use a *helper* function like this:

```
Function GetID(strng As String)
    Dim el As Variant

    For Each el In Split(strng, ",")
        If InStr(1, el, "cn=") > 0 Then
            GetID = Mid(el, InStr(1, el, "cn=") + 3)
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next
End Function
```

and your main code would exploit it as:

```
If InStr(1, vText(i), "cn=") > 0 Then ws.Range("b" & rcount) = GetID(CStr(vText(i)))
```

Comment: I have tried your solution but i got compile error: Byref Argument type mismatch. and the error was showing on "vtext" in this line:  = GetID(vText(i)), any idea?? thanks

Comment: see edited code, where I added the use of `CStr()` function to convert a `Variant` into a `String`

Answer (score 0):

The trick here is to use the Split() function

```
Dim Arr() As String
Dim j As Integer
Dim k As Integer
Dim strvar As String
Dim strval As String
Dim strID As String

If InStr(1, vtext(i), "cn=") > 0 Then

    ' split the whole line in an array - "," beeing the value separator
    Arr = Split(vtext(i), ",")

    ' loop through all array elements
    For j = 0 To UBound(r) - 1

        ' find the position of =
        k = InStr(Arr(j), "=")

        strvar = Left(Arr(j), k - 1) ' this is the variable name, ie "cn"
        strval = Mid(Arr(j), k + 1) ' this is the value, ie "SVCLMCH"

        ' now do what you want with a specific variable

        Select Case strvar

            Case "cn"
                strID = strval

            Case Else
                ' do nothing
        End Select

    Next j

End If
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. May i know how to write the outcome to cells (b & rcount)?

Comment: Your ID is in `strID`, thus :  `ws.Range("b" & rcount) = strID`

Answer (score 0):

*Use [Regular Expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expression-language-quick-reference) extract the [ID](https://regex101.com/r/67u84s/1/) from the [sentence](https://regex101.com/r/67u84s/1/)*

***Example `Pattern = "(?<=cn=)([^.]+)(?=\,OU=Users)"`***

https://regex101.com/r/67u84s/2

*Code Example*

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub Examplea()
    Dim Matches As Variant

    Dim RegEx As Object
    Set RegEx = CreateObject("VbScript.RegExp")

    Dim olApp As Object
    Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

    Dim Item As Outlook.MailItem
    Set Item = olApp.ActiveExplorer.Selection.Item(1)

    Dim Pattern As String
        Pattern = "(?<=cn=)([^.]+)(?=\,OU=Users)"
    With RegEx
        .Global = False
        .Pattern = Pattern
        .IgnoreCase = True
         Set Matches = .Execute(Item.Body)
    End With

    If Matches.Count > 0 Then
        Debug.Print Matches(0).SubMatches(0)
        With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
            .Range("A1").Value = Trim(Matches(0).SubMatches(0))
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```